# PHP.ini how to enable timezone extension

Tags: php

I get the following error in my application:

> The upload feature requires timezone extension enabled in the PHP.

I'm using Plesk as a CP and I've checked the php.ini too but can not solve this issue. Has anyone had anything like this before?

PHP Version: 5.3.10

Comment: Search in your project for that string. Find which condition it is checking against to show that error. There's no timezone extension unless it means [this](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).

Comment: The DateTime extension is [built into PHP 5.2+](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php), there shouldn't be anything to enable.

Comment: I think you need to look into your php.ini and enable the timezone extension. Useually you just need to uncomment the appropiate line.

Comment: Thanks guys let me check with the developer and I'll update you here.

Comment: Why is everyone voted my post down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to possibly replace an empty `date.timezone` value. In Plesk (the latest version being 12.0.8) go to your specific domain overview page (to set the timezone at domain level), click on the big link stating your domain, now you'll see a tab "PHP Settings", scroll all the way down to 'Additional configuration settings' and **set** your timezone e.g. `date.timezone = “US/Central”`

Comment: After doing a bit of Google work, it seems the error message also includes the string "[Check how to set it up](https://suporte.scriptcase.com.br/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/69/0/configuring-datetimezone-in-phpini)" which yes, indicates that this is caused by a missing date.timezone setting. Good guess. :-)

Comment: Thanks did the job, added the following to the settings section: date.timezone = "Europe/London"